# Efficient string constructor

Tags: c++, string

Some classes I meet, have a dual string constructor:

```
 construct( const std::string& s );
 construct( const char* s );
```

Having a `std::string` constructor has the obvious benefit of being able to pass a `std::string` without `c_str()`. However, if the argument is stored in a std::string anyway, is there any benefit of having the `const char*` constructor?

In particular:

```
 construct( const std::string& s ) : m_string( s ) {}
 construct( const char* s ) : m_string( s ) {}
 std::string m_string;
```

Will the second constructor be faster for string literals and `char*` variables, or will it be optimized away?

Additional question - does C++11 move construction change anything here?

Comment: In C++11 with move construction, you can use this (as a single ctor for both): `construct(std::string s) : m_string(std::move(s)){}`. Not as efficient as perfect forwarding, but almost (two moves for a temporary).

Comment: `std::string("Hello There")` that's why you have a constructor for a `const char*`, but I'm not sure what you are asking here ...

Comment: it don't has to be faster, it's only a overloaded second constructor for a simpler handling

Comment: Perfect forwarding from C++11 is also possible here: `template<typename T> construct(T&& s) : m_string( std::forward<T>(s) ) {}`

Comment: @DyP: For a temporary, the first move will most probably be elided, leaving a single move. Under the assumption of small object optimization this can be a few tens of bytes. Without small object optimization probably something like 3 or 4 pointers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++03, or in C++11 without specifying move semantics, the `const char *` to `std::string` implicit conversion creates a temporary string, which then gets copied to the member. This implements an extra copy.

In C++11 you can have the temporary moved instead after passing by value:

```
construct( std::string s ) : member( std::move( s ) ) {}
```

The only other thing I can think of is compatibility with other classes providing conversion operators.

```
struct String {
    operator char const * () const;
};
```

Since only one user-defined conversion may apply implicitly, the `std::string` function won't receive a `String` argument by conversion through `char const *`. Note, however, that with an additional conversion function to `std::string` and both constructors, the result would be overload ambiguity.

Comment: The other problem is (as I noticed) that it won't undergo implicit construction from a literal... is the implementation with std::move() better performance wise?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz I don't understand. Nothing here is protecting against literals, can you illustrate the issue? And you don't need to call `std::move` to get move semantics from a temporary. If there's any difference, moving from a temporary is probably slower than constructing from a direct pointer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter The point is if you use `construct(std::string const& p) : m_string(p)` you'll copy the temporary.

Comment: If "construct( const std::string& s )" is your only constructor, the class wont implicitly construct from a literal. Or is that a VS bug?

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz That doesn't sound right to me. What VS version?

Comment: @DyP Oh, thanks! Fixed now, that was a serious omission on my part.

Comment: 2012, but *not* Nov'12.

Comment: @KornelKisielewicz Dunno… I don't have any version at all. Does it work with the constructor RiaD (and now I, although I didn't look at his answer until after :P ) suggest?

Answer (score 5):

If you have just `char*` and only first constructor, copy may be made 2 times. `in std::string(char*)` and in `construct(std::string)`

While in second constructor pointer will be copied(it's fast) and then string copied.

In C++11 good idea is to create 1 constructor

```
 construct(std::string s ) : m_string( std::move(s) ) {}
```

In this case if you have just `char*` data may be copied in string ctor, but string will be temporary, so it will be just moved in `construct` ctor

[This code](http://pastie.org/8188419) prints "creating, copy"
[This code](http://pastie.org/8188424) prints "creating, move"

Comment: Why would it copy 2 times?

Comment: @billz, In string(char*) ctor and then in construct(string)

Comment: @DyP, copy&paste is evil:) fixed